# Calculating age based on a birthdate in MS access

Tags: ms-access

I want to calculate a persons age based on a birthdate  in ms access this is what i have tried

```
DateDiff("yyyy", [birthdate], Now())+ Int( Format(now(), "ddmm") < Format( [birthdate], "ddmm") )
```

But it gives me the error:

```
The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to change it?

Comment: In order to say what is wrong with the expression, please add a note as to where it is: a control, code etc.

Comment: If these DOB fields don't have time of birth included, why are you using Now() in your calculation, instead of Date()? It won't fix the problem, but it is the correct function to use with Date calculations where the time component lacks significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=85

```
''True = -1, False = 0
Age = DateDiff("yyyy", Birthdate, Date) + _
             (Date < DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Birthdate), Day(Birthdate)))
```